# Amazon In App Billing passing values to PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest for displaying the item contents like price,title

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, amazon-in-app-purchase

I am working on Amazon In app Purchase for Android I want to display the price of the item on the user interface but I am unable to get how to display the price?

There is a method called `PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest` but I dont know what I need to pass to that method so that it will call the `onItemDataResponse` and will give the details?

**EDIT:**

Please see my below Answer.

Comment: Why down voted? is this not a valid question?

Answer (score -1):

And Yes Finally after doing lot of research got to know how can i get the price to display below is the procedure:

```
        Set<String> skuSet = new HashSet<String>();
        skuSet.add("Your sku string here");
        PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest(skuSet);
```

Now we will are passing the sku to the `initiateItemDataRequest` , now after this method is called a method called `onItemDataResponse` in the `ButtonClickerObserver` class will be called automatically then it will call the `ItemDataAsyncTask().execute(itemDataResponse);`

where we can update the price in our UI TextView or Button Text, it can be done in this way, just override this method in the `ItemDataAsyncTask()`.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            baseActivity.updateButtonWithPrice(itemPrice);// here i am setting the price of the Button Text
        }
```

Note : updateButtonWithPrice(itemPrice) is a method which is with string as args which i have written in my activity.

Hope this will help in the future for others. :)